# No messages on Jquery validation with Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate

I am using Dan Cochran's bootstrap jQuery validator, http://alittlecode.com/jquery-form-validation-with-styles-from-twitter-bootstrap/ and I want to remove the messaging aspect but keep css classes for highlighting errors and sucesses for required fields.

My code is as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    validator = $('#form1').validate({
    rules: {
        ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$forename: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        return false;  //Suppress all messages
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element.addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        //element.text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    }
});
```

The errorPlacement function works in that it removes the messaging and therefore the original span created contained text 'OK!' however the success function breaks in removing the error class and applying the success class.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Got this to work using errorPlacement, highlight and unhighlight functions...
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            return false;  //Suppress all messages
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        },

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below.